# How can I plot in horizontal lines along X axis corresponding to a value on the y axis?

Tags: matlab, plot, vector, matlab-figure

I have 2 arrays Q and Z. I want to plot Q on the y-axis and Z on the x-axis. The elements of Z are 0s and 1s.

What I want is to draw a horizontal line from one '1' to the next '1'.
E.g. in vector Z, the first 1 to the next 1, has its corresponding y value as the first element of Q, Then the 3rd 1 to the fourth 1 has its y value as the 2nd value in Q and so on.

now i will have several _ _ _  (horizontal lines spanning length of the distance between the 1s as plots)

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Q and Z are column vectors, you could do something like this:

```
Q2=[Q,Q];
inds=1:numel(Z);
inds=inds(Z==1);
X=reshape(inds',2,numel(inds)/2);
```

At this point, Q2 and X should have the same dimensions (two-column matrices).
Then plot the horizontal lines beside each other:

```
plot(X,Q2)
```

Or above each other, starting at x=0 with different lengths:

```
X2=[zeros(numel(Q),1),diff(X)]
plot(X2,Q2)
```

I'm not at a computer so I can't confirm details on returned dimensions.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your input. gave me some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the endpoints of each horizontal line with `find()`, then plot the lines with `plot`.

```
Q = [1 2 3 4];
Z = [1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1];
z_endpoints = find(Z);

figure;
for i = 1:numel(Q)
    plot(z_endpoints([i*2-1,i*2]),Q([i,i]))
    hold on
end
hold off
```

To get the lines all the same color and in the same plot, you can put the points in a vector with NaNs (not-a-number) to produce the gaps. A bit more work, but with a cleaner plot.

```
Q = [1 2 3 4];
Z = [1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1];
z_endpoints = find(Z);

zpoints = [z_endpoints(1:2:end-1);z_endpoints(2:2:end);nan(size(Q))];
zpoints = zpoints(:);

qpoints = [Q;Q;nan(size(Q))];
qpoints = qpoints(:);

plot(zpoints,qpoints)
```

Comment: The first example worked. In my work, the Z is a huge vector of length (256688) making the scaling very small. is there a way to rework the scales or axis to bring into focus these horizontal lines?

Comment: How many lines do you have, and how long are they on average? Do you care about their lengths and spacing being true to scale?

Comment: the number of lines is the same as the length of my Q which is 434. I don't care about the length. but the scale I care about because, in reality, Z is a signal I'm working with. so those points are the samples of the signal, that's why it's very long.

Comment: or is it possible to shrink the scale, with a high step size so that, even if the markings are not exactly the same, it falls in the interval? e.g. if the first 2 points making the first horizontal line were between 2 and 3, it can fall between 1 and 5 now.

Comment: If you don’t care about the length of the lines, the easiest way would be to replace the odd Z’s with the even Z’s that precede. Then each line would extend to the start of the previous line. If you wanted to be fancier, you could shrink the inter-line Z spacing proportionally throughout, to preserve a little of the original character. If either of these would meet your need, I’ll add it to my answer above.